# How to use Linq in C# to do this?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Object:

```
class Car 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

public enum Color
{
    Red = 1,
    Blue = 2,
    Pink = 3,
    Orange = 4,
}
```

How to create a linq query if I want take objects which have Red and Blue values:

```
query = query.Where(at => at.Color == Color.Red + Color.Blue);
```

Comment: This isn't really a LINQ question. You're really just asking how to write a Boolean expression and that's not something you should have to ask.

Comment: In your code example the objects can only have one colour. They cannot be both red and blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I take you at face value, and you want cars to be able to have more than one colour then you need to change your `enum` to use the `Flags` attribute.

Like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Color
{
    Red = 1,
    Blue = 2,
    Pink = 4,
    Orange = 8,
}
```

Now I can write this code:

```
var cars = new []
{
    new Car() { Name = "Red & Orange", Color = Color.Red | Color.Orange },
    new Car() { Name = "Red & Blue", Color = Color.Red | Color.Blue },
};

var query = cars.Where(at => at.Color == (Color.Red | Color.Blue));
```

That, indeed, returns just the `"Red & Blue"` car.

However, if you meant ***or*** rather than ***and*** then you don't need to change your `enum` and the following is what you need:

```
query = query.Where(at => at.Color == Color.Red || at.Color == Color.Blue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you can make the query with `||` or operator

```cs
query = query.Where(at => at.Color == Color.Red 
    || at.Color == Color.Blue);
```

Or create an `Color` array to check whether the value is within the array.

```cs
query = query.Where(at => (new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue }).Contains(at.Color));
```